# docker java7 install fail

Tags: java, docker

I'm trying to install java7 via ppa (RUN  add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y) in my docker image but it fails with this error:

```
returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The following are suggested ways to install correctly but it's not working. I've tried both ppas as well.

```
RUN  apt-get install python-software-properties -y
RUN  add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
#RUN add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y
```

Here is the log output:

```
Step 28 : RUN  add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
 ---> Running in b278761a4209
 [91m/bin/sh: 1: add-apt-repository: not found
 [0m
```

So...I need to find out where/if this command exist in a helper lib or what:

```
add-apt-repository
```

add-apt-repository appears to be a part of the python-software-properties install. I don't see any real errors in that step except for these messages which pop up in other areas of the build. So I *assume* that if I can resolve this issue the aforementioned python step will install as needed:

```
    [91mdebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
     debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
     debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
     [0m[91mdebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
     debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
     debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
     [0m[91mdpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

So. How to set a term or dialog up? I thought the -y allowed this

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `-y` in your `apt-get install` commands is telling `apt-get` to "assume yes", which isn't the same as running in non-interactive mode.

You're seeing the "unable to initialize frontend: Dialog" messages because Debian is running `apt-get` in interactive mode. To tell it to run in non-interactive mode, add this line to the start of your Dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

Now your commands will be running in non-interactive mode, so `apt-get` won't try and pop any dialogs up.

As for your actual error, you're right, `add-apt-repository` is a part of the `python-software-properties`.  Try putting your `apt-get update -y` command above your `apt-get install python-software-properties` command.

```
RUN apt-get update -y                             && \
    apt-get install python-software-properties -y && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y    && \
    apt-get update -y                             && \
    apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y     && \
    oracle-java7-set-default
```

Note, you'll need to do two `apt-get update -y` commands, one before you start (always a good habit to get into) and one after you've added the oracle java PPA.

[apt-get manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

[Docker ENV docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env)

Comment: No worries - enjoy docker!

Comment: Yes, loving it so far. I've showed it to a few peers and they like it as well. It may replace our current vagrant solutions if I can get this spike done.

Comment: I found I also needed these two lines from http://askubuntu.com/a/190674:
 RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections

Answer (score 14):

`add-apt-repository` command is a part of software-properties-common pakage. Install software-properties-common, not python-software-properties.

Then you can add ppa:webupd8team repository. But there is still a problem.

Set the accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 and install java. Below sample Dockerfile will work perfectly.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not help with this exact problem. I'm so glad I tried your solution. Worked like a charm.

Comment: for me, installing software-properties-common didnt work but installing python-software-properties from the answer above did.

Comment: Work for me: echo password | mysqlrouter --bootstrap xxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 4):

#### Way #1

Somebody said this way not working but i tested it works.

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

yes | apt-get install package-1 package-2
```

#### Way #2

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

apt-get install -y package-1 package-2
```