# Dockerfile - How to pass an answer to a prompt post apt-get install?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I am trying to install jackd2 package:

```
RUN apt-get install -y jackd2
```

It installs properly, but after installation, I can see the following prompt:

```
If you want to run jackd with realtime priorities, the user starting jackd
needs realtime permissions. Accept this option to create the file
/etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf, granting realtime priority and memlock
privileges to the audio group.

Running jackd with realtime priority minimizes latency, but may lead to
complete system lock-ups by requesting all the available physical system
memory, which is unacceptable in multi-user environments.

Enable realtime process priority? [yes/no]
```

```

At this point, I would like to answer with either yes or no, hit enter and move on but I have no idea how to script this inside a dockerfile and my build hangs right there.

Comment: Tried `yes | apt-get install -y jackd2`?

Comment: @kichik Might need to be `yes yes | apt-get ...`

Comment: I have tried both, none of these works. Besides I might have to answer with a "no"

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could start with your base image, install jackd2 manually, use `docker commit` to turn your container into a new image, and use that new image as a base for your Dockerfile to start from.

Comment: unknown instruction: yes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019183/docker-java7-install-fail/25020555#25020555) has an explanation for the difference between "assume yes" and a non-interactive mode.

I also found an example of a Dockerfile that installs jackd2 [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/oriaks/scenic/~/dockerfile/), and it's setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to `'noninteractive'` before installing jackd2.