# How do I answer install prompts (other than with "yes") automatically?

Tags: dockerfile, apt, tex-live

### Synopsis

I'm trying to build a Docker image, but it fails because one of the packages I'm trying to get with `apt install` prompts the user during the install process. I would like to reply to this prompt, but I can't figure out how to do it non-interactively.

### Description

I'm building a Docker image, and my Dockerfile has the following line:

```
RUN apt install -y texlive-latex-extra
```

(This package has some LaTeX libraries that I need.)

During installation, this halts with:

```
Setting up tzdata (2018d-1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa        6. Asia            11. System V timezones
  2. America       7. Atlantic Ocean  12. US
  3. Antarctica    8. Europe          13. None of the above
  4. Australia     9. Indian Ocean
  5. Arctic Ocean  10. Pacific Ocean
Geographic area:
```

At this point, it is waiting for some input. (There's another prompt after this for selecting timezone—I assume this is important to know for the `\today` directive in LaTeX files. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

How can I answer this non-interactively?

### What I've tried so far

I've tried doing this:

```
apt install -y texlive-latex-extra <(echo 12 && echo 2)
```

and this:

```
echo 12 && echo 2 | apt install -y texlive-latex-extra
```

The first one died with this error:

```
apt install -y texlive-latex-extra <(echo 12 && echo 9)
```

and the second one seemed to have no effect.

For reference, here is my Dockerfile up until this point:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y curl bzip2 tar make gcc wget gnupg unzip
RUN apt install -y texlive
RUN apt install -y nodejs npm git
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN apt install -y texlive-latex-extra
```

### UPDATE

I found something close [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160592/dockerfile-how-to-pass-an-answer-to-a-prompt-post-apt-get-install?rq=1) which suggested running `apt install` with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. This solved my problem sufficiently. :) *However*, I still would like to know how to respond to prompts, as the solution offered there only offered how to suppress them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to script a terminal interaction, you could use [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) on Linux (that might not be very easy; you need to predict the interactions).

Remember that [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) are complex and arcane things (because [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) like [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) have been complex). See [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) and read [*The Tty demystified*](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Comment: Solid. Thanks! Could you provide an example of using `expect` in a case like this?

Comment: No. I forgot most of expect. Used it more than twenty years ago. In general, you should not need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The specific install prompt mentioned in the question is caused by the package `tzdata`. I managed to get it configured non-interactively in my docker build by setting these environment variables:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get install -y texlive-luatex texlive-latex-extra texlive-font
```

I found this solution over here: https://serverfault.com/questions/949991/how-to-install-tzdata-on-a-ubuntu-docker-image