# During docker build, Ubuntugis installation freezes during configuration

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, gis

During `docker build`, when it reaches this command, `RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`, the dependency requires user input during installation. However, after I input a response and press enter, the build process never continues and it just stalls (I've waited close to 30mins, but it shouldn't take even a second to load). Network connection is fine, resources shouldn't be a problem, and I've tried both the stable and unstable versions.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25020555/2596409) is showing how to run in noninteractive mode. Basically it's saying to:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the use input with and see if it still stalls

```
RUN add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
```

Comment: The problem is I need to input a number (1-12), so -y or --yes won't answer the prompt. I believe you can echo an input but i don't understand how to write that in the dockerfile